# select based on where condition in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have the following query:

```
SELECT i_platform_id
     , s_campaign_id 
  FROM tbl_reports 
 WHERE 
     ( s_campaign_id IN ('00012702a67dd038','00012702a67dd037') 
    OR i_platform_id IN ('1','2')
     ) 
 GROUP 
    BY i_platform_id
     , s_campaign_id
```

my goal is to get the campaigns or the platforms based on this query but i want to get in the select the campaign id if found in s_campaign_id and i_platform_id if found in platform. so basically it should look like

```
campaign          platform
00012702a67dd038   - 
00012702a67dd037   -
-                   1
-                   2
```

now i am getting the platform and campaign columns always filled
using union all

```
SELECT COUNT(b_entry_type_tag)::decimal * 1 AS tags,(COUNT(CASE WHEN b_entry_type_red = true AND s_request_type NOT IN ('Y0', 'YX') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))::decimal * 1 AS redirects,COUNT(b_entry_type_cnv)::decimal * 100 / NULLIF((COUNT(CASE WHEN b_entry_type_red = true AND s_request_type NOT IN ('Y0', 'YX') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))::decimal * 1,0) AS crp,SUM(f_revenue) * 1000 / NULLIF((COUNT(CASE WHEN b_entry_type_red = true AND s_request_type NOT IN ('Y0', 'YX') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))::decimal * 1,0) AS rrm,COUNT(b_entry_type_cnv) AS conversions,COALESCE(SUM(f_revenue),0) AS revenue, s_campaign_id, NULL as s_campaign_id  FROM tbl_reports WHERE s_campaign_id IN ('00012702a67dd038','000134d57335e431') group by s_campaign_id,i_platform_id 

union all

SELECT COUNT(b_entry_type_tag)::decimal * 1 AS tags,(COUNT(CASE WHEN b_entry_type_red = true AND s_request_type NOT IN ('Y0', 'YX') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))::decimal * 1 AS redirects,COUNT(b_entry_type_cnv)::decimal * 100 / NULLIF((COUNT(CASE WHEN b_entry_type_red = true AND s_request_type NOT IN ('Y0', 'YX') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))::decimal * 1,0) AS crp,SUM(f_revenue) * 1000 / NULLIF((COUNT(CASE WHEN b_entry_type_red = true AND s_request_type NOT IN ('Y0', 'YX') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))::decimal * 1,0) AS rrm,COUNT(b_entry_type_cnv) AS conversions,COALESCE(SUM(f_revenue),0) AS revenue, i_platform_id , NULL as i_platform_id   FROM tbl_reports WHERE i_platform_id IN ('1','2') group by s_campaign_id,i_platform_id
```

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `union all`?

```
SELECT i_platform_id, NULL as s_campaign_id 
FROM tbl_reports 
WHERE s_campaign_id IN ('00012702a67dd038', '00012702a67dd037') 
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL as i_platform_id, s_campaign_id 
FROM tbl_reports 
WHERE i_platform_id IN ('1', '2');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer is there other way to do it?

Comment: @YossiBondasd . . . In MySQL, this is probably the simplest way to do this.  Is there a reason why you don't like this method?

Comment: i actually using postgre sql

Comment: @YossiBondasd . . . This is still a fine solution, although you could also use a lateral join.